# Removing "bar" above the iphone keyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, keyboard, iqkeyboardmanager

In an iPhone app, when the user clicks a `UITextField`, this keyboard is displayed. I would like to remove the bar/area containg "<", ">" and "Done".

Any suggestions how to do that?

[image: The keyboard toolbar]

**SOLVED**
It turned out that it was `IQKeyboardManager` that was adding the bar on top of the keyboard.

It was removed by this line in AppDelegate file:

```
IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enableAutoToolbar = false
```

Comment: Is the from a `UITextField` or an input field in a web view? If it is really from a `UITextField` then the toolbar must be one you have added. Simply don't add it.

Comment: Thanks, you let me on the right track

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try :

```
self.<yourTextField/View>.inputAccessoryView?.hidden = true
```

Comment: Hmm, this wasn't the solution after all - se updated issue